# ios Azure Mobile Services objective c update/modify item error

Tags: azure-mobile-services

I'm trying to update a field in Azure Mobile Services (javascript backend) from my iOS client, but without success. The code is returning errors (I basically copied the code from the sample provided [here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/mobile-services-ios-how-to-use-client-library/#modifying)) when I execute my app for the update operation. (it works fine for the read and insert)

You can view my code below:

```
NSMutableDictionary *myDic = [item mutableCopy]; //item is the old dictionary
            [myDic setValue:@"Romanos" forKey:@"verseTitle"];
            [self.table update:myDic completion:^(NSDictionary *item2, NSError *error2) {
                // Handle error or perform additional logic as needed

            }];
```

However, when I execute it, I receive error messages (from the attached breakpoint) about:

```
3+[NSError errorWithDomain:code:userinfo:]
4-[MSJSONSerializer errorWithDescriptionKey:andErrorCode:]
5-[MSJSONSerializer errorForInvalidItemId]
6-[MSJSONSerializer itemIdFromItem:orError:]
7+[MSTableRequest requesToUpdateItem:withTable:withSerializer:completion:]
9-[MSTable update:completion:]
9_29-[ViewController viewDidLoad]_lbock_invoke
10__58+[MSTableConnection connectionWithReadRequest:completion:]bl_block_...
11-[MSConnectionDelegate connectionDidFinishLoading:]
12___ZL32_NSURLConnectionDidFinishLoadingP16_CFURLConne...
```

The error I receive is the following:
2015-08-17 15:17:34.097 Palavra do dia[13214:88493] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Invalid domain=nil in -[NSError initWithDomain:code:userInfo:]'
*** First throw call stack: (
    0   CoreFoundation                     0x00a9c746 __exceptionPreprocess + 182
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00725a97 objc_exception_throw + 44
    2   CoreFoundation...

Please, any ideas in how to I fix it?

If I surround the code with a @try and @catch, I view the following message in my log: ]

Invalid domain=nil in -[NSError initWithDomain:code:userInfo:]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you update a record, you have to include the id of the record you are updating. You didn't include the actual error message from the Azure SDK, but judging by the stack trace you included, the item NSDictionary you tried to update  had an "id" key, but the value was neither an NSNumber nor an NSString.

What do you have in the 'item' NSDictionary? If it came via the Azure SDK from a table you created with Mobile Services, it should have a string id.

**Edit for comment below**
Your filter with the NSPredicate will still give you an NSArray with one object (rather than the item itself), so to get the item out of the array and get its id, you'll need to do

```
NSDictionary *item = filteredArray.firstObject;
NSString *itemId = item[@"id"];
```

In order to see what the error is according to the Mobile Services SDK, you can log it in the completion block:

```
[self.table update:@{@"id":@"E5B33C88-332F-4C4A-A8A9-EA0CDC4A1DF3", @"verseTitle":@"Update test"} 
    completion:^(NSDictionary *item, NSError *error) {

    if (error)
        NSLog(@"Error updating item: %@", error);
        // ... and handle the error
    }
}];
```

Comment: I`m using a NSPredicate to filter my call, so that I`m returning a single row, with the following data for the ID:
[1] (null) @"id" : @"E5B33C88-332F-4C4A-A8A9-EA0CDC4A1DF3"

I'm trying to update one of the values of my table's row from that call using the NSString ID, with the following code: (I'm trying to do that inside the first return call)

[self.table update:@{@"id":@"E5B33C88-332F-4C4A-A8A9-EA0CDC4A1DF3", @"verseTitle":@"Update test"} completion:^(NSDictionary *item, NSError *error) {}];

I receive he same errors, even if I run this code from another method,  what am I doing wrong?